# Conjugate transpose and discreteness, for Kleinian groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, discrete-geometry

Let $G=\langle g_1,\dots g_n\rangle<\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ be discrete,
i.e. a finitely generated Kleinian group.
Let $H=\langle g^{\dagger}g\mid g\in G\rangle$,
(the group generated by the $g^{\dagger}g$)
where $g^{\dagger}$ is the conjugate transpose.

Under what conditions is $H$ discrete?

**Edit: In light of comments from @Misha, below I am removing my claims about what I can prove and adding some motivation for the question.**

In the spinor representation of the restricted Lorentz group, $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{C})$
is faithfully represented as the group of orientation-preserving isometries of the hyperboloid model $\mathbb{I}$ for hyperbolic 3-space.
In this construction, we identify the points on $\mathbb{I}$ with the Hermitian matrices of norm 1, up to identification of $\pm1$.
Then for $(g,p)\in\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{C})\times\mathbb{I}$
the action can be defined by $g(p)=g^{\dagger}pg$.
Skipping some details, the point $p=(1,0,0,0)\in\mathbb{I}\subset\mathbb{R}^4$
is identified with the identity matrix.
So in this construction, the set $\{g^{\dagger}g\mid g\in G\}$
is identified with the orbit under $G$
of $p$.
It is for this reason that I said this set is certainly discrete.

I am working on a more elaborate duality between points in hyperbolic space and isometries of that space using quaternion algebras. I am holding back some info because this is part of my thesis which is not published, and my school would not be too happy if I posted certain ideas online at this point. So suffice it to say I have interesting applications using the group $H$ generated by that set.

Comment: Isn't this just because conjugate-transpose is a homeomorphism, so the image of a discrete subgroup is ditto? Maybe I'm misunderstanding something...

Comment: @paulgarrett  Yep you're right, made a typo there. Fixing now.

Comment: Is $H$ the group generated by $g^tg$ or is it just the set $g^tg$?

Comment: I have edited the question to make this more clear. Thanks @Venkataramana for drawing attention to this.

Comment: What is your definition of an arithmetic group? With the definition that I know, there are arithmetic groups for which $H$ is not discrete: Each Bianchi group is conjugate to such. Also, could you explain the origin of the question?  (I find the setting very strange since the answer changes when we conjugate $G$ to another subgroup.)

Comment: I mean arithmetic in the sense of Borel and Harish-Chandra. If $G$ is a Bianchi group then it is closed under complex conjugation, so we would have $H\leq G$, and since $G$ is discrete, so is $H$.

Comment: It appears that you are not using the standard notion of arithmeticity, which is invariant under conjugation in $SL(2,C)$. What you have is: If you take the standard integer structure on $SL(2)$, then indeed for arithmetic groups defined with respect to this structure the group $H$ is discrete. However, to define arithmetic subgroups (in general) you have to consider all integer structures.

Comment: @Misha Okay I need to rethink this, let me edit the question and put in more about my motivation after the weekend.

Comment: Even this is not completely clear; even after a conjugation, there is no reason why the arithmetic group should be invariant under conjugate transpose. The only general class of arithmetic groups for which this appears to be true are the Bianchi groups

Comment: @Venkataramana Okay I will remove that claim. $G$ does not need to be invariant under conjugate transpose for $H$ to be discrete, but nonetheless I'm not at liberty to go into my reasoning regarding that.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a thought about your question. Suppose that $G$ contains a unipotent element $u$. Then we can conjugate $G$ to $G'=hGh^{-1}$ such that $u$ conjugates to $u'=huh^{-1}$ which is close to $1\in SL(2,C)$. Note that if $u_1, u_2$ are two such commuting unipotent elements then $v_i=(u_i')^{\dagger} u_i'$, $i=1, 2$, will not (generically) commute. Therefore, by Jorgensen's inequality (or Zassenhaus Lemma if you prefer), the subgroup generated by $v_1, v_2$ will be nondiscrete. I suspect, one can play a similar game in greater generality and prove that for any infinite discrete subgroup, its conjugate $hG h^{-1}$ leads to  nondiscrete subgroup. This definitely applies to "generic" geometrically infinite finitely generated Kleinian groups. But for convex-cocompact groups cannot use Jorgensen inequality argument and one needs a different approach.

Comment: This does give me a new perspective, particularly the role of finitely generated geometrically infinite groups as studied by Jorgenen. On the other hand this class of groups does not play in to my application (which I know I was vague about). I'm also content with finding a single conjugation of $G$ whose corresponding $H$ is discrete, but as you mentioned earlier it is strange when a property is not invariant of conjugation.

Comment: Woops, typo: Jorgensen not Jorgenen.

Answer (score 2):

The map that you have written down is equivariantly identified with the map
\begin{align}
\mathbb{F}(\mathbb{H}^3)\rightarrow \mathbb{H}^3
\end{align}
where $\mathbb{F}(\mathbb{H}^3)$ is the bundle of oriented, orthonormal frames over hyperbolic 3-space $\mathbb{H}^3.$  Being a fiber bundle with compact fibers, this maps discrete sets to discrete sets.  In particular, this does not require that the discrete set of points in $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ forms a group.

Comment: This is excellent news! Give me a day or so to get around to looking up what you've explained to verify, before check-marking your answer.

Comment: But $H$ is the group $generated$ by $g^tg$; even if the generating set is a discrete subset, it does not mean that the group generated is discrete.

Comment: I interpreted $H$ as a set, but now I see this may not have been the authors intention.  In this case, what I've said above certainly doesn't imply that the group generated by such elements in discrete.  I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Andy: your interpretation may be correct, since the OP says this is true for arithmetic lattices (I think you can get arithmetic lattices where the group generated is not discrete. If so, my apologies for creating confusion where there was none before!

Comment: $H$ is the group generated by the elements specified. Discreteness of the set of those elements is certainly guaranteed.

Comment: In light of this last comment, what I've said certainly does not solve the problem.